# NameError referring to variable in instance method

Tags: python

I am learning Python (using v3.6) from the book "Crash Course in Python". In the last chapter, I came across this example, but when I run it, it throws an error. Please suggest what am I doing wrong. I can't figure it out.
Note: Both programs are in the same folder.

```
**survey.py**
class AnonymousSurvey():
    def __init__(self, question):
        """Store a question, and prepare to store responses."""
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        """Show the survey question."""
        print(question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        """Store a single response to the survey."""
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        """Show all the responses that have been given."""
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in responses:
            print('- ' + response)


**Survey class use**

from survey import AnonymousSurvey

question="What languages so you know?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
my_survey.show_question()

print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit.\n")
while True:
    response = input("Language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)

# Show the survey results.
print("\nThank you to everyone who participated in the survey!")
my_survey.show_results()

ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "survey_usage.py", line 6, in <module>
    my_survey.show_question()
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\python_training\Chapter 11\survey.py", line 10, in show_question
    print(question)
NameError: name 'question' is not defined
```

Comment: `self.question` should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print `self.question`, not `question`. In general, when accessing instance variables within the class, you need to explicitly use `self`.

Comment: Thanks. That did take care of nameError for "questions" but now seeing this:         Survey results:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "survey_usage.py", line 17, in <module>
    my_survey.show_results()
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\python_training\Chapter 11\survey.py", line 19, in show_results
    for response in responses:
NameError: name 'responses' is not defined

Comment: It's the same thing—you need `self.responses`, not `responses` because (in Python) you **must** explicitly refer to instance variables of a class using `self`.

Comment: You've misunderstood me. `self.response` is nothing. You need `for response in self.responses`, because `self.responses` was a class variable you defined. `response` was declared in the local scope; it doesn't need `self`.

Comment: Thanks, added self in this line : "for response in self.responses: " worked. :)